# Sql Server: Get first row after the given data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am preparing a query to fetch data from DB using SQL Server. Please find below query. There is a table `AssociateStatus`. This table contains the current status of the associate. `AssociateStatus_HST` table contains all the status changes. I want status changed date in `[Status Changed Date]` column.

With my query, I will get all the updateddates after status 3. But I want only next updateddate alone. Please note that status change can happen in any order.

```
SELECT 
    AssociateId,[Status], UpdatedAt, 
    ASH.UpdatedAt AS [Status Changed Date] 
FROM
    AssociateStatus_HST AST 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (SELECT
         ProposalBidId,UpdatedAt
     FROM
         AssociateStatus_HST) ASH ON (ASH.StatusID = AST.StatusID AND ASH.UpdatedAt > AST.UpdatedAt)
WHERE 
    [Status] = 3
```

Sample output from this query:

```
  AssociateId   Status  UpdatedAt  Status Changed Date
 --------------------------------------------------------
  1234            3       21-1-19       24-1-19
  1234            3       21-1-19       27-1-19
  4567            3       20-1-19       25-1-19
```

Expected output

```
  AssociateId   Status  UpdatedAt  Status Changed Date
 --------------------------------------------------------
  1234          3       21-1-19    24-1-19
  4567          3       20-1-19    25-1-19
```

Comment: share sample data and its output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Added sample data

Comment: Just use MIN(ASH.UpdatedAt) OVER (Partition By AssociateID)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `GROUP BY` without subquery:

```
SELECT 
   AssociateId, 
   [Status], 
   Max( UpdatedAt) UpdatedAt, 
   Min(ASH.UpdatedAt) AS [Status Changed Date] 
FROM AssociateStatus_HST AST 
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssociateStatus_HST ASH
    ON 
        ASH.StatusID = AST.StatusID and ASH.UpdatedAt > AST.UpdatedAt   
WHERE [Status] = 3
GROUP BY AssociateId, Status
```

And an example(I've modified date to ANSI format):

```
DECLARE @FooTable TABLE
(
    AssociateId INT,
    Status INT,
    UpdatedAt VARCHAR(50),
    StatusChangedDate VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @FooTable
(
    AssociateId,
    Status,
    UpdatedAt,
    StatusChangedDate
)
VALUES
  (1234,          3,       '2019-21-1', '2019-1-24')
, ( 1234,          3,       '2019-19-1',    '2019-1-19')
, (4567,          3,       '2019-1-19',    '2019-1-25')

SELECT 
  ft.AssociateId
, ft.Status 
, MAX(ft.UpdatedAt) UpdatedAt
, MIN(ft.StatusChangedDate) StatusChangedDate
FROM @FooTable ft
GROUP BY ft.AssociateId, ft.Status
```

OUTPUT:

```
AssociateId Status  UpdatedAt   StatusChangedDate
1234    3   2019-21-1   2019-1-19
4567    3   2019-1-19   2019-1-25
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT AST.*, ASH.*
FROM AssociateStatus_HST AST OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) ASH.UpdatedAt AS [Status Changed Date] 
      FROM AssociateStatus_HST AS ASH
      WHERE ASH.AssociateId = AST.AssociateId AND AST.StatusID = ASH.StatusID AND ASH.UpdatedAt > AST.UpdatedAt AND ASH.[Status] = 3
      ORDER BY ASH.UpdatedAt 
     ) ASH'
```

Comment: This isn't doing any filtering for status = 3.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()` function

```
select * from 
(
SELECT AssociateId,[Status],UpdatedAt, ASH.UpdatedAt AS [Status Changed Date],
row_number() over(partition by AssociateId order by ASH.UpdatedAt) as rn
FROM AssociateStatus_HST AST 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ProposalBidId,UpdatedAt FROM AssociateStatus_HST 
) ASH ON 
ASH.StatusID = AST.StatusID and ASH.UpdatedAt > AST.UpdatedAt
WHERE [Status] = 3
) A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

use row_number() window function

```
with cte as (

SELECT 
   AssociateId,[Status],UpdatedAt, ASH.UpdatedAt AS [Status Changed Date] 
  ,row_number() over(partition by AssociateId,[Status] order by ASH.UpdatedAt) rn
FROM AssociateStatus_HST AST 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT
    ProposalBidId,UpdatedAt
FROM
    AssociateStatus_HST 
    ) ASH
ON (
    ASH.StatusID = AST.StatusID and ASH.UpdatedAt > AST.UpdatedAt
)
WHERE [Status] = 3
) select * from cte where rn=1
```